# Saving image to the destination path with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a registration which also includes uploading a photo. Here's my code register controller code.

This the function to store data in the database

```
protected function create(array $data) //storing data to database
{
    $fileName = 'null';
    if (Input::file('photo')->isValid()) {
        $destinationPath = public_path('public/uploads/files');
        $extension = Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = uniqid().'.'.$extension;

        Input::file('photo')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
    }

    return Travelers::create([
        'fname' => $data['fname'],
        'lname' => $data['fname'], 
        'gender' => $data['gender'],
        'username' => $data['username'],           
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'birthday' => $data['birthday'],
        'photo' => $fileName,
    ]);

}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using `public_path()` helper. so you don't need to include `public/` again.
use 
`public_path('uploads/files')` 
instead of 
`public_path('public/uploads/files');`